# Same spacing in list of figure and table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script, line-spacing

I have tweaked the spacing in my `scrbook` table of contents using

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=1em plus 1pt]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=2pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=2pt]{subsection}
```

Does KOMA-Script provide a similar command for spacing in the list of figures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=2pt
]{default}{figure}
```

The size of the chapter gap between the entries in LOF and LOT can be changed by

```
\KOMAoptions{chapteratlists=1em}
```

The gap can also be disabled by `listof=nochaptergap` or replaced by entries for all (even if there are no figure/table) chapters  by `listof=chapterentry`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=1em plus 1pt]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocbeforeskip=2pt]{section,subsection}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=2pt
]{default}{figure}
\KOMAoptions{chapteratlists=1em}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\blinddocument

\captionof{figure}{Figure One}
\captionof{figure}{Figure Two}

\chapter{Another Chapter}

\captionof{figure}{Figure Three}
\captionof{figure}{Figure Four}
\end{document}
```